# How to define $i in linux bash shell?

Tags: linux, bash

I am having a problem while using the bash shell. Here is my linux command code:

```
for i in `cat linshi`;do sed -i '/$i/d' a.txt;done
```

The content of linshi is:

```
aa
bb
```

The content of a.txt is:

```
aa:wwersdf12314231234
bb:weorpius2345234523
cc:ertoiu230498234098
dd:234092834asdfkdfkg
```

I want to delete the first and the second row of a.txt.

But unlucky, I found '/$i/d' is not correct. And I have tried '/\$i/d' and '/"\"$id/', but they are fail again. Who can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables aren't expanded inside single quotes, only double quotes.

```
for i in `cat linshi`; do sed -i "/$i/d" a.txt; done
```

That said, you could do the same thing with:

```
grep -vf linshi a.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using single quotes use double quotes. `''` doesn't undergo any variable expansion however double quotes do.

This will work:

```
for i in $(cat linshi);do sed -i "/$i/d" a.txt;done
```